# Spectral values of vegetation

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

How do I use Google Earth Engine to extract the spectral values of Sentinel-2 2A data from winter wheat samples?

In the data I obtained, the reflectance of some dates in the blue band is greater than that in the red band or the green band is lower than that in the red band.

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection('users/lixiyu/dongxiaomai/sub_areas/tdt_dancheng_sample')
var points=ee.FeatureCollection(table);
var roi=points;
print(points);

//var lists =points.toList(points.size()).zip(array.toList());
var array = ee.Array(ee.List.sequence(1, 30, 1));

var lists = points.toList(points.size()).zip(array.toList());

var features = ee.FeatureCollection(lists.map(function(l) {
  return ee.Feature(ee.List(l).get(0)).set('PID', ee.List(l).get(1));
}));
print(features);


Export.table.toDrive({
 collection: features,
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  description: 'pointCoordinates'});   // save the lat and lon of point


function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .set({ 'system:time_start': image.get('system:time_start') });
}


var bands = ['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11','B12'];//,,'NDVI


//ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED") Level-1C
//ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED") Level-2A

var collection1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') //_SR_HARMONIZED
                  .filterDate('2018-10-01', '2019-06-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  //.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .select(bands); 
                 
print(collection1);
//'COPERNICUS/S2_SR'
//COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED
      // 统计影像的数量
      var count = collection1.size();
      print('Count: ', count);
      // 从影像集合中获取影像时间的范围并且进行打印看看效果
      var range = collection1.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"]);
      print('Date range: ', ee.Date(range.get('min')), ee.Date(range.get('max')));

  // // 在集合中获取影像的属性值
  //     var sunStats = collection1.aggregate_stats('system:time_start');
  //     print('system:time_start: ', sunStats);



var bands = ['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11','B12'];//,,'NDVI


var ft = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([]));

var fill = function(img, ini) {

  var inift = ee.FeatureCollection(ini);

  var ft2 = img.sampleRegions({
   collection:features,
//  properties:ee.List(['id']),
   properties:ee.List(['PID', 'Id', 'name','lat', 'lon']), 
  scale:10
  });
  var date = img.date().format();
  var ft3 = ft2.map(function(f){return f.set("date", date)});
  return inift.merge(ft3);
};




// Iterates over the ImageCollection
var newft = ee.FeatureCollection(collection1.iterate(fill, ft));

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: newft,
  description: 'S2_winter_wheat_points',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Comment: Although QA60 band is a great tool for masking clouds, the borders of clouds, shadows generated by clouds, and cirrus are always tricky for the algorithm. If you are using the SR product, using the classification band instead of QA60, will improve the masking process. I recommend you to check the dates where you see this unexpected behavior, probably the clouds are affecting the scene. Also, since you loaded TOA products as well, do you see this behavior in both quality levels?

Comment: The dates of the abnormal data are mostly in April. I later used the "Cloud Score+ S2_HARMONIZED" dataset to optimize the cloud removal function, but the problem still exists.